# animate a line and make it au turn css3

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a line. I am moving that from left to right. Which is fine. But Now I want to turn it in a u turn way or like a snake. How can I do that?

```css
.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: move 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {}
  to {
    left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but hope it helps.

```css
.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: move 5s 1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

Comment: Not exactly. The u turn is fine but it is not like a snake. It should be more like flexible. I mean the line should become flexible when it turns back.

Comment: As it can be seen here https://www.uplabs.com/posts/menu-arrow-animation

Comment: @null this isn't really possible with pure css, you'd need to use some svg animations.